# json_decode not returning data

Tags: php

I am using curl to get the data from API, It works well with some but for some function the json_decode function not returning the data. Not sure what exactly cause the problem here, as if I directly check the API it has the data but not getting through json_decode function.

Comment: Some code will be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Copy your API response JSON into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/). If it's not valid, you have a problem.

Comment: Just `echo $subAccID;` and copy that into JSONLint. You need to make your code more defensive. Not only are you assuming cURL was successful, but you're assuming that the data returned is valid JSON. And now you're here on S.O. ;)

Comment: Yes, I check it in JSONLint and it has some error. As the data returning is not from my end, I just need to show that details in my end. But thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yep sorry if you want to use `json_decode` PHP must be provided with valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Is the return data well-formed? You can try parsing the return data using [JSON Lint](http://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http://www.jsonlint.com/&rct=j&q=json%20lint&ei=4ZFtTrWoJMjsrAf93PmYBQ&usg=AFQjCNGAWyUxNl2wssqNPiq-Z0pgQKO0Pw&cad=rja) first.

Comment: Yes the data has some errors. I checked that, I need to show that details in my end and can't able to get the data as I has errors. But thanks for your help.